# tween.js - Setting default easing values

Tags: javascript, tween.js

I'm using https://github.com/sole/tween.js/ and creating a lot of tweens - is there a way to set a default value for the .easing property so I don't have to declare it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the library, but having looked at the code, it unfortunately seems that it has not been created for that.
In fact, if you look at the source code, the `easing` function in the `TWEEN.Tween` constructor is private.
You could change the code of the library yourself, or you could decorate the constructor.
A simple way to achieve that is to overwrite the constructor by substituting it with a function that creates a `TWEEN.Tween` object, runs the `easing` function and returns the created tween.
The following code has to be included just after the TWEEN library, and before your code.

```
TWEEN.origTween = TWEEN.Tween;
TWEEN.Tween = function (options){
    var res = new TWEEN.origTween(options);
    res.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
    return res;
};
```

You could take the example further and implement some other "default" values yourself by calling other methods inside the newly defined "constructor".
Please note that the defaults can be changed at any time using the .easing method like you have being doing until now, even after the decoration of the constructor function.

Here is a working fiddle with the default easing function set to `TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut`

http://jsfiddle.net/5fgn2/

As you can see, by uncommenting the `easing` invocation, you can still change it, if you need to.